# How to get all column data of one part of the many-to-many relationship to be joined by comma, and get only one row?

Tags: mysql

There is a many-to-many relationship between two tables; say between Author and Book tables. Let's say the junction table is AuthorBook.

Let's suppose one book has been written by 2 authors. I want to get the authors of a book :

```
select b.title, a.name 
from book b join authorbook ab on b.id = ab.bookid 
join author a on ab.authid = a.id 
order by b.title;
```

Normally for every book, there is a different row for the author associated to it; in this case there will be 2 rows. What I want is to display just one row where the authors will be "joined" by comma. How to achieve that ?

Comment: this can useful for you, SELECT 
    GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT v
        ORDER BY v ASC
        SEPARATOR ';')
FROM
    t; For oracle https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/functions089.htm#SQLRF30030

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example